# Unidirectional OneToMany relationship without joinTable

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

In order to achieve a foreign key column (no joinTable) when mapping a unidirectional OneToMany relationship, i follow the steps according to Grails (version 2.2.3) reference documentation, [section 6.5.2.1](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#tableAndColumnNames) OneToMany mapping, which states

> With unidirectional associations the foreign key needs to be specified on the association itself. For example given a unidirectional OneToMany relationship between Person (replaced by One) and Address (replaced by Many), **the following code will change the foreign key in the Many table**

```
class One {

    static hasMany = [manyCollection:Many]
    static mapping = {
        manyCollection(column:"ONE_ID")
    }

}
```

However, when i run

```
One one = new One()
one.addToManyCollection(new Many())

one.save()
```

I get in the console

```
insert 
into
    one
    (id, version) 
values
    (null, ?)

insert 
into
    many
    (id, version) 
values
    (null, ?)

insert 
into
    one_many
    (one_many_collection_id, many_id) 
values
    (?, ?)
```

Notice Grails create a joinTable called one_many. So, my question: it is a bug or something else ? What should i do to get rid of the joinTable ?

Even when i use something like

```
class One {

    static hasMany = [manyCollection:Many]
    static mapping = {
        manyCollection(joinTable:false)
    }

}
```

as highlighted [here](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/grails-one-to-many-mapping-with-foreign.html), i get the same output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there, you have 2 halves of the mapping but you need both for it to work correctly. It's not a well documented feature but I've used this before and it definitely works (e.g. no join table). So in your One class,

```
class One {
  ..
  static mapping = {
    manyCollection column: "ONE_ID", joinTable: false
  }
}
```

NOTE: it's probably a good idea to exit, clean and restart grails when making mapping changes. I've lost many hours banging my head when a simple grails clean was the solution.

Also, you could technically add `belongsTo` **without the back reference** in your Many class and you would still have a true uni-directional but with the added benefit of cascading action (mapped in One class) if it's something you need.

Comment: The reference documentation is wrong. **We should use joinTable:false** instead of column. If i use only column as stated by the documentation, a joinTable will be created.

Answer (score 0):

The following setup will implement what you are talking about:

```
class One {
   static hasMany = [manyCollection: Many]
}

class Many {
   static belongsTo = [one: One]
}
```

If you want to delete the many if it gets removed from the ones collection, add:

```
  class One {
      static mapping = {
          manyCollection cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
      }
  }
```

Comment: Your solution is a bi-directional relationship, NOT a unidirectional one